# Async waterfall inside async series

Tags: node.js, asynchronous

Is it possible to use `async.waterfall` inside of `async.series`?

So for example, say I have a module `api` that has two methods, `api.get` and `api.post` and then another module that downloads an image from S3 bucket, resizes it, and then puts it back into the S3 bucket, `resizer`.

I want to issue a get request with `api.get` and get an `oauth` token, then trigger `resizer` and only then trigger `api.post`. I don't need to pass any results between `api` and `resizer`.

So far I have something like this:

```
async.series([
  function get (callback) {
    api.get(callback)
  },
  async.waterfall([
    function download (callback) {
      S3.get({...}, callback);
    },
    function transform (response, callback) {
      gm(..)
        .resize(....)
        .toBuffer(...) {
          S3.put({...})
        }, callback;
   ]),
   function post (callback) {
     api.post(callback)
   }
], function (err) {
      ......
});
```

But it never triggers `api.post` and dies after `S3.put`. Why?

Comment: In the future please post actual syntactically valid JavaScript. It's unpleasant to parse pseudocode and it defeats syntax highlighting and auto-formatting tools. You can make up placeholder variable names if you like but `settings` is valid javascript where `....` is not.

Comment: @PeterLyons will do. Sorry about that.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Absolutely it's possible. I do the same thing all the time. It can get a bit messy so that's something to watch out for though.

The reason your code isn't being called is because you need to wrap the waterfall in another function. Currently the way you have it your outer async.series would try and invoke the result of async.waterfall, which probably doesn't return a function.

```
async.series([
  function get(callback) {
    api.get(callback)
  },
  function(callback) {
    async.waterfall([
      function download(callback1) {
        S3.get({...
        }, callback1);
      },
      function transform(response, callback1) {
          //transform stuff here
          return callback1();
      },
      function post(callback1) {
        api.post(callback1)
      }
    ], callback);
  }
], function(err) {
  ......
});
```

Comment: As @Ivan said with the code you have you don't need to use waterfall within your async.series. Async.waterfall and async.series are essentially the same thing: they both run a set of asynchronous functions in order. However, I have used async.parallel within async.series or async.waterfall. This can be very helpful if you need to run a bunch of 'steps' in order and one of those steps has multiple sub steps that you want to run in parallel.

Comment: But if I use only `async.series`, as @ivan has said, then how do I pass the result from `S3.get` to my `transform` function?

Comment: If you need the result of each function to be passed to the next one that is what async.waterfall is for, so use that in place of async.series. The only different between async.waterfall and async.series is that waterfall will pass the result of each function to the next.

Comment: @officert is right you can call it how he did, but wrapping it in a function as series expect as an element of its chain. I didn't want to say it's impossible, I was saying in that way

Answer (score 1):

You cannot call `waterfall` in the middle of `series`, basically because `waterfall` doesn't return any thing and series expect a function as task, so you're breaking the chain.

With example you posted, I don't understand why you need both, using `series` should be enough.